# when sum two columns in different table the record sum duplicate

Tags: sql-server

```
table 1          table2

   k2   id          k1  id
    3   1           3   1
    3   1           3   1
    3   1           3   1
    5   2           5   2
    6   2           6   2
    7   2           7   2
    7   2           7   2
    7   2           7   2
                    5   2
```

output i need is:

```
id   sum k1    sum k1
1       9        9
2       37       32
```

Here is the query i used:

```
select table1.id,sum(table1.k1),table2.id,sum(table2.k1) from table1,table2
where table1.id= table2.id
```

but output i have not right

Comment: There ain't no k1 column in table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(table1_result.id1, table2_result.id2) AS id 
  , table1_result.sum_k1 AS sum_k1 
  , table2_result.sum_k2 AS sum_k2 
FROM 
                  ( SELECT id AS id1, SUM(k1) AS sum_k1 FROM table1 GROUP BY id ) AS table1_result 
  FULL OUTER JOIN ( SELECT id AS id2, SUM(k2) AS sum_k2 FROM table2 GROUP BY id ) AS table2_result 
    ON table1_result.id1 = table2_result.id2
```

The first sub-query in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT id AS id1, SUM(k1) AS sum_k1 FROM table1 GROUP BY id
```

will give you a result of

```
id1      sum_k1 
1        9 
2        37
```

And likewise, the second sub-query will give the sum for table 2.

```
id2      sum_k2 
1        9 
2        32
```

The outer query matches the `id` values from both sub-queries and displays the respective sums from table 1 and table 2 alongside one another.

```
id       sum_k1     sum_k2 
1        9          9 
2        37         32
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple combination of `UNION` and `GROUP BY` will give you desired result. Here you go..

```
SELECT id,max(SumK1) AS SumK1,max(SumK2) AS SumK2 FROM
(
    SELECT ID, sum(k1) AS SumK1, NULL AS SumK2 FROM table1 GROUP BY id
    UNION
    SELECT ID, NULL AS SumK1, sum(k2) AS SumK2 FROM table2 GROUP BY id
) T
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `table1` has `id` and `k1` column. So, you can do this:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) id,
sum(t1.k1) sum_t1_k1,
sum(t2.k1) sum_t2_k1
from table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2
t1.id = t2.id
group by coalesce(t1.id, t2.id);
```